# Possible to send a Firebase push notification to device without wifi?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

None of my notifications sent to device token come through on Android when the device is out of wifi or on mobile data.  Is this a limitation of the platform or is there a config that can be set to allow for data notification to mobile data?

Comment: Hi. AFAIK, so long as the device is able to establish a decent connection with the FCM server, regardless of the connection, push notifications should be available.

Comment: I think the issue is with your mobile data connection speed, and I have tested apps with FCM using mobile data and they work just fine

Comment: Make sure power saving is not on, that can interfere with background data. Also, please post the JSON you're using for sending the FCM message.